In an interview how to ask about access to internal job postings?
I have an interview coming up. Frankly the position isn't a great fit and I'm overqualified for it in terms of education. But I've heard good things about the company. Is there a way to ask if there is some sort of internal job posting pool and if so when would I be able to apply to the jobs? I know some organizations have policies about hiring internal workers first, especially if they are unionized. I suspect this is such a place and am wondering what I can ask to find out without making it sound like I'm not interested in the current position?

Just curious why the close vote?

I tell job hunters to go for the position to get their foot in the door.  When a better fit position comes along, then go for it.  I did this myself at a shop.  They hired me as a project manager until a software position opened up.  They knew I was interested in a S/W position, so when it became available, I was the first person they asked.

if it's internal, surely it's not meant for external viewers?

"sound like I'm not interested in the current position" but it sounds like you aren´t, though?

Ask about career development and, when this project ends, how the company handles reassignment with that growth in mind.
(My ex-employer used to be very good about helping folks with the latter. Now... well, that's why they're my ex-employer.)

I don't think you can ask this without it looking like you're not interested in the advertised position.  Look at it from the interviewer's perspective, you don't even have the position yet and you are already asking how to find the next position.
You might be able to get there through asking how teams are built and managed, or how often there are reorganizations.  This might lead the interviewer down the path of discussing internal transfers.  If they do follow that path, it would be fair to ask them to explain more.
I would steer clear of asking this directly during your interview.

Is that a bad thing? Being ambitious is not a negative.

That's a bit unfortunate as it would really help me decide if I want the job if I had an idea about advancement opportunities.

Most jobs other than temps have advancement opportunities.

@DJClayworth It is and isn't... When a company is hiring for a position, they want the person they hired to do that job. Not spend all of their time campaining/wishing for a different job.
Some ambition is good. Too much ambition and I know you won't want to stay in the position long enough for it to be worth hiring you to fill that position.

Usually, you want to be interviewing for the job at hand, if they find something better for you, let them do it.  Don't act like your "better" than the job you are applying for.

@ClanLatin, seems like you've already decided you don't want this job though, you want some better job at the same company.  If that's the case apply for that job or wait for it to be posted.

@JosephDoggie Some companies like to recruit smart people who will grow and provide more value than their current job title would indicate. Lots of companies look for management potential in their recruitment, even at lower levels.

@ClanLatin Then ask about advancement opportunities. That is a far better way of putting it and shows ambition, as opposed to disinterest

There is another angle why, from a hiring team's POV, this is terrible: even if OP does not manage to get into a different role soon, they may end up resentful and disgruntled. This is basically a no-win scenario for the hiring team.

@DJClayworth Although true, giving signals during your job interview that you're already interested in looking for your next job after that job will be a bit of a red flag that you're not really interested in the job you're applying for right now.

@MarkRotteveel Some people said that, and my comments were saying why I disagreed.

@DJClayworth Being ambitious and having plans for the future is great, but if I really need some one for position X, I prefer to hire someone who wants position X for mid to long-term, not someone who I may have for a short while, trying to get position Y within my organization and just using position X as a stepping stone. In other words, asking about this in the way the OP wants to do, instead of maybe more generally asking about career opportunities and growing in the organization, might not be the best way to get the job.

@MarkRotteveel And there are a couple of different type of positions. There are entry level positions. Whose entire purpose is to funnel hires into bigger better positions inside of the company. and then there are jobs that exist because they need someone to XYZ.... WIthout know what the job is, one cannot say either way. But entry level jobs tend to have a clear progression into a better paying but clearly related job. Which doesn't appear to be what OP is asking about.

At my previous company (a large multinational), I had multiple candidates ask me about internal transfers, and I didn't hold it against them. This is in part because internal transfers were quite common at my company, so there was no stigma against them. When interviewing people, we saw ourselves as interviewing them for the company + job type + job level as much as for the specific team. (In fact, for complicated reasons not worth going into here, new hires often ended up joining a different team from the one they'd actually interviewed with.)
To see if that's the case at a potential employer, without making clear your reasons for the question, you could ask something like "Do [role] at [company] tend to stay on the same team for many years, or do people tend to move around within the company?"
But, a caution: at my company, if you were overqualified for the specific role you were interviewing for, then you would probably also be overqualified for any role that you might readily transfer to. Internal transfers were not a mechanism for promotion; if you "got your foot in the door" at the wrong level, it could take a few years before you proved yourself and got promoted to the right level.
So your best bet might be to see if you can identify one of the interviewers as not being on the specific team you're interviewing for (which should be easy to do: you should be asking questions about the team anyway, so it's totally reasonable to ask the interviewer their relation to the team), and if so, they should be less invested in wanting someone who'll stay in the specific role you're applying to for a long time. So you can ask them about opportunities for advancement at the company, how promotions and internal transfers work, and so on, with less risk of sending a red flag.

"see if you can identify one of the interviewers as not being on the specific team you're interviewing for" Some organisations require at least one member of the interview panel to be outside the hiring team as an anti-nepotism/corruption measure.

@nick012000: Indeed, the company I discuss in this answer had a rule along those lines, though in our case it was more about making sure that teams never lowered their standards out of eagerness to fill a position quickly. But even aside from that rule, at every company I've worked at, interview loops always just naturally have people from multiple teams. (Of course, that only applies to the kind of position where you get interviewed by multiple people. If the OP's interview is more "cattle call"-like, then that might not turn out to be the case!)

I believe it really depends on the role you are applying to. If this is clearly an entry-level or temporary position where rotation is to be expected, I think asking about internal advancement opportunities is fair game - good even, as comments say, showing ambition is normally a good thing. I work in a university, and for our lower-level non-scientific roles (e.g., student support, some administrative roles) it's generally a good thing if candidates indicate that they would be interested in eventually transitioning into a larger and more permanent role (economist, etc.).
For some temporary roles, particularly paternity / maternity leave replacements, positions are explicitly advertised as a good way to get into the system (and we indeed have an obligation to prioritise such candidates for other openings they are qualified for).
However, the executive term here is eventually - if it's not a temporary position, you should not be looking to transfer this year, nor next year, but maybe a few years down the line. Obviously, you should not frame your question as "I am overqualified but need a foot in the door", frame it as a good learning opportunity that would put you in a prime position to deliver value to the organization for a long time.

However, if you are already applying for a somewhat advanced, normally permanent role, I don't really see a way to phrase the question without immediately appearing as a flight risk. You say:

what I can ask to find out without making it sound like I'm not interested in the current position?

Well, you are not interested in the current position. It's going to be hard to hide this.
While ambition is good and advancement opportunities are something that companies are proud of, advancement is normally within the same line of role (e.g., going from developer to lead developer to engineering manager), not transferring into a completely different team (going from technical sales into engineering). While for an organisation transferring might still be good, the team that does the actual hiring may see things very differently. They still went through all the effort of hiring and onboarding, and still have to repeat the whole process again quickly after. Organisational priorities and the priorities of the hiring team are not always aligned.

There are a lot of unknown variables at play.
Within that, I have worked a long time at a large organization with a lot of opportunities for movement within the organization. I have not yet found a negative reaction to asking "how long do you expect me to stay in this position?" Obviously, if you get a promotion the next day your boss will understand (or you don't want that boss anyway), but understanding the expectations up front is pretty reasonable.
So, if you lean on that as your starting point, I think you can reasonably ask what you want. Roughly: "I am interested in this position specifically, and also in working for your company generally. If I take this position though, I recognize you're taking a chance on me, and I want to stay in it long enough to make a difference. You know [company] much better than I do though: What do you think is a reasonable amount of time to dedicate to [position]?" This is also a good opportunity to gauge reaction. (One year and three years are the common answers I hear, but YMMV wildly.)
Either way, once you've laid that groundwork, you can more easily ask about your original question: "I'm really interested in growth opportunities within [company] afterwards. Can you tell me anything about internal opportunities, and how they get published?"
